# using iajc with java 1.8 JDK -- Comparator cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, ant, aspectj

The source code for the project I work on is managed within eclipse but the .class and .war files we actually use and ship are built using ant via a build.xml file.  The code works in a Spring environment and uses AspectJ to do some compile-time weaving.  We've been working with AspectJ 1.6 and Java 1.6 for several years, but we are now in the process of trying to move to using Java 1.8 (a jboss environment which we've been installing within has been using Java 1.6 but is being moved to 1.8; plus we are also working to decouple our application from the other application so we can run standalone inside a jetty container where we provide Java 1.8), but there seems to be a problem between the use of AspectJ and Java 1.8.  I've found a number of posts which seem to be related to the issue we're seeing, though I've not found any of them to provide a simple solution that seems to match our particular build situation (those that do have potential solutions at all always refer to something like maven or other things which we are not using).

Here's the error output we see when trying to compile using Open JDK 8 from Zulu (8u31 for Windows):

```
 [iajc] C:\GitRepos\NSE_decouple\client\src\com\hp\nonstop\nse\test\cli\sort\PhysicalTargetListByName.java:5 [error] Comparator cannot be resolved to a type
 [iajc] public class PhysicalTargetListByName implements Comparator<String>
 [iajc]                                                  ^^^^^^^^^
 [iajc] C:\GitRepos\NSE_decouple\client\src\com\hp\nonstop\nse\test\cli\sort\PhysicalTargetListByName.java:5 [error] The type java.util.Comparator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
 [iajc] public class PhysicalTargetListByName implements Comparator<String>
```

The particular code in question referenced in this error (I suspect other code would be failing as well, but this failure seems to stop the compile) is:

```
public class PhysicalTargetListByName implements Comparator<String>
{
<code not included; the declaration itself seems to be the failure point>
}
```

In case the problem was related to using aspectj1.6, I installed the latest version of AspectJ as well, which is AspectJ 1.8.5, but that made no difference.

Things build OK within eclipse itself, but we get the errors when trying to build using ant, with JAVA_HOME set to "c:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-8" and IAJC_HOME set to "c:\aspectj1.8" before doing "ant build" at the command line.  Within the build.xml file, we have the following step inside a build target task to perform the iajc compile:

```
 <iajc destdir="${build.dir}" failonerror="true" 
     showWeaveInfo="${showWeaveInfo.isEnabled}" source="1.6" target="1.6"  
     debug="true"  fork="true"  maxmem="256m">
    <src path="${instsrc.dir}" />
    <exclude name="**/junit/*"/>
    <exclude name="**/install/*"/>
    <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
    <aspectPath refid="aspectPath"/>
 </iajc>
```

I've also tried this with both source and target set to "1.8" as well but that makes no difference either.

The build.xml file also contains:

```
<path id="aspectPath">
   <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/spring-aspects.jar"/>
</path>
```

and

```
<path id="master-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${jetty.dir}/lib">
        <include name="servlet-api-3.0.jar"/>
        <include name="jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar"/>
        <include name="jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${jetty.dir}/lib/jsp">
        <include name="javax.servlet.jsp-2.2.0.v201112011158.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <pathelement location="${clover.jar}"/>
    <pathelement path="${build.dir}"/>
</path>
```

An experiment where I replaced the <iajc> task with a <javac> task instead allowed the build to work without the error (though the code produced would not have been woven) so it does appear that the error is related to the mixture of AspectJ with java 1.8 (another experiment shows that we can build without the error when using Open JDK 7 and AspectJ).

And help pointing to what we might need to do to get AspectJ to work with Java 1.8 builds would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some poking around, and a little bit of serendipity, I **finally** managed to find what was keeping the fixes I'd tried up to that point from solving the problem.

It came down to the existence of a copy of aspectjtools.jar within my `%ANT_HOME%\lib` folder.  This JAR had been placed there many, many (**many**!) years ago.  It happened to be the AspectJ 1.6 version of the JAR and its existance there caused ant to use that version even though our build.xml file had been modified at some point to specify the path to AspectJ so an existence of the JAR under the ant lib was not needed to determine the version to use(and which I'd recently changed to point at AspectJ 1.8 instead, though the presense of the file made my change to build.xml ignored).  Even though I thought I was now using AJ 1.8 with Java 1.8, I was not, so all the fundamental problems of incompatibility between older AJ and Java 1.8 remained.

Once I removed that JAR from the ant lib folder, my ant builds worked as expected without errors!

So the fix was to remove a file which wasn't needed, but which hadn't caused a noticeable problem up to that point, since we'd been using AJ 1.6 for many years previously.  The update to the newer version didn't really take effect because of the stray file's existence.  No file ==> build.xml config takes effect ==> compile works!